# Using the 'Encrypted' property in AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration BlockDeviceMapping BlockDevice to encrypt EBS root volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I am trying to encrypt the `EBS` root volume in an `AutoScaling` group, but cannot seem to find a way to do it in `CloudFormation`.

Here is the applicable section of the `CFT`:

```
Resources:
  LaunchConfiguration:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Metadata: ...
    Properties:
       KeyName: <VALUE>
       ImageId: <VALUE>
       SecurityGroups: <VALUE>
       InstanceType: <VALUE>
       BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: <VALUE>
              VolumeType: <VALUE>
              Encrypted: True
```

This `CFT` works and encrypts the attached `EBS` volume with the default `KMS` key in the account. It doesn't, however, encrypt the `EC2` root volume `xvda`. I have tried adding the following to `BlockDeviceMappings`:

```
- DeviceName: /dev/xvda
  Ebs:
    Encrypted: True
```

I get a `CloudFormation` error, so this doesn't seem to work. I have checked the `AWS` Documentation for `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` located [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html), but I can't seem to find where it addresses encrypting an `EC2` root volume in an `AutoScaling` group.

Given my environment's configuration, I can't enable default volume encryption for `EC2`, so I am looking for a way to accomplish this via a `CFT`.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: `"You must specify either a VolumeSize or a SnapshotId."` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig-blockdev-template.html

Comment: @PatMyron Thanks for the reply. I think that requirement only applies to that particular attribute. I went ahead and defined the `VolumeSize`, but it still didn't work. It seems to be an issues with Encryption of `EBS` volumes in an `ASG` period. I enabled default encryption for all `EBS` volumes in our account in `EC2` settings, and it failed as well, so it seems to be an issues with encrypting `ASG` `EC2` root volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I didn't have the appropriate `IAM` role authorized to use my `KMS` `CMK`. All I had to do was authorize the `AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling` role for the 'CMK' and it built the stack without issue. The root volume is also encrypted.